# Input Centric approach vs Output Centric approach to solve algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, producer-consumer

I am struggling with understanding the difference between these two approaches in solving problems.

From what i've read:
"Input-centric strategy: In this approach, you process one input at a time and build the partial solution with each iteration.
Output-centric strategy: With this approach, you add one output to the solution at a time and build the partial solution iteratively."

For me, these two statements mean basically the same thing. Are there any practical examples of solving one problem by using two different approaches?

Comment: I think this is related to push vs pull, consumer vs producer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of sorting algorithms: *insertion sort* versus *selection sort*:

1. Insertion sort processes one input at a time, in the order they occur in the input, and places that value at its temporary correct place in the sorted partition. This might not the final position for that value. This would be an example of *input-centric* strategy.
2. Selection sort adds one output to the solution at a time. This value is searched among the input. The found value will be placed at its final position. This would be an example of an *output-centric* strategy.